# Kак запретить открытие окна во весь экран PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, windowflags

Задача в том, чтобы убрать вот эти кнопки

[image: Нужно убрать выделенные кнопки]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно создать фиксированное окно, это можно сделать так:

```
window.setFixedSize(width, height)
```

Но это позволит лишь не раскрывать окно на весь экран, а вот чтобы его нельзя было сворачивать нужно поработать с флагами:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window. setFixedSize(500, 300) # задаем фиксированный размер
flags = window.windowFlags()       # получаем все флаги которые есть
flags &= ~Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint  # отключаем ненужный нам флаг
window.setWindowFlags(flags)  # присваеваем флаги окну
window.show() 
app.exec()
```

*Возможно вместо фиксированного размера вам нужно просто отключить флаг`WindowMaximizeButtonHint`.*

Моя рабочая среда `linux` поэтому вероятно это особенности `X11`, что нельзя отключить кнопку минимизации, результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще есть такие флаги (их можно найти в [документации](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-dev/overviews/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html)):

```
Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint
Qt.FramelessWindowHint
Qt.WindowTitleHint
Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint
Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
Qt.WindowShadeButtonHint
Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint
Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
```

Для того чтобы не путаться в флагах Вы можете обратится к этому [исходнику](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/widgets/windowflags.py)

Запустив его у Вас будет не только удобная работа с флагами, но и возможность их скопировать в свой код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @KostyaKhmylov , мне кажется что этот ответ не только правильный, но и полезный для вас. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour